# solution for error in gradle flutter when i run code on mobile

Tags: flutter, gradle

i was run the code on mobile it was working after that i rur the code in web and it's work but when i back to run on mobile happen this error
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A4jO.png)

this is build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
       mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i try use `./gradle clean` and the same error ,i try delete cach gradle but not working

Answer (score 1):

remove repository from `build.gradle`
and add this code to `settings.gradle`

```
// Configure plugin management repositories
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal() // Official Gradle Plugin Portal for Gradle plugins
        google()             // Google's Maven repository for Android dependencies
        mavenCentral()       // Maven Central repository for Java dependencies
    }
}

// Configure dependency resolution management
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    // Set repositories mode to fail if project-specific repositories are detected
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    
    repositories {
        google()             // Google's Maven repository for Android dependencies
        mavenCentral()       // Maven Central repository for Java dependencies
        
        // Custom repository for fetching libraries from JitPack
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io" // JitPack repository URL
        }
    }
}

// Set the root project name 
rootProject.name = "your_porject_name"

// Include the 'app' module in the project
include ':app'
```